# Blank Transactions on block explorer but returns successful in code

Tags: web3.js, transactions, jsonrpc-api, javascript, send-transaction

How can I prevent this from happening https://solscan.io/tx/3gphnLPNXHMkE2M8QgRgGXkUPZtZsxs2PEeSZVPBUfmEUemKnpasR3AV6QAVjgsVia5LtCXp9nAK512KvqynfxTm ?
Or make it so those are retried until success? Here's how I handle transactions -

```
/**
 * @returns { Promise<number> }
 */
async isBlockhashExpired(initialBlockHeight) {
    const currentBlockHeight = await this.solanaConnection.getBlockHeight();

    return currentBlockHeight > initialBlockHeight;
}

/**
 * @returns { Promise<string> }
 */
async handleTransaction(transactionInstructions, signer, retries = 1) {
    try {
        if (retries >= 5) throw new Error("Max retries reached. Solana might be down or we might be experiencing techincal issues. Please try again later.");

        const signature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(this.solanaConnection, transactionInstructions, signer, { commitment: "" });

        if (!signature) {
            return await this.handleTransaction(transactionInstructions, signer);
        }

        await this.wait(2 * 1000);

        let isBlockhashValid = true;
        const inititalBlock = (await this.solanaConnection.getSignatureStatus(signature)).context.slot;
        let done = false;

        setTimeout(async () => {
            if (done) return;

            done = true;
            return;
        }, 30 * 1000);

        while (!done && isBlockhashValid) {
            const transaction = await this.solanaConnection.getTransaction(signature, { maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0 });

            if (transaction) {
                done = true;
                return signature;
            }

            isBlockhashValid = !(await this.isBlockhashExpired(inititalBlock));
            await this.wait(300);
        }

        await this.wait(2 * 1000);

        const transaction = await this.solanaConnection.getTransaction(signature, { maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0 });

        if (!transaction) {
            retries++;
            return await this.handleTransaction(transactionInstructions, signer, retries);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        // error handling
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code of you sending the transaction. This is just your code trying to confirm it.

Comment: @Ahri `sendAndConfirmTransaction` method is responsible for that which is present in the code posted above.